# Chrome: Changing img src repeatedly causes chrome to request image again?

Tags: javascript, html, image, google-chrome, setinterval

Same title. I'm not sure if this is a browser bug or behavior, see below example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var srcs = [
                    'https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIH1O.jpg?s=48&g=1',
                    'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/9aa2aa68144b2781ac025a29c83bbdd4?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG',
                    'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/c0377fc1b08293d3362611978913a32b?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG',
                    'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/07f36acea2b942f61102221f92f62f6e?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG',
                    //
//                    'data:image/png;base64,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',
//                    'data:image/jpeg;base64,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',
//                    'data:image/png;base64,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',
//                    'data:image/jpeg;base64,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',
                ];
                var $x = $('#x');
                var i = -1;
                setInterval(function() {
                    ++i;
                    if(i >= 4) {
                        i = 0;
                    }
                    $x.attr('src', srcs[i]);
                }, 100);
            });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id="x" width="50" height="50">
    </body>
</html>
```

Every few random seconds, the images are requested again, although fetched from disk cache, but request is happening. If you resize window, the requests may happen even more frequently.

Check [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wsp0c4uo/)

[image]

I tried using base64 images instead of URLs, still same thing. This is an issue because the visible image may glitch/flicker when request occurs.

**EDIT**

How to prevent chrome from requesting the same image again?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Placing multiple `img`s, hide all and show only 1 at a time, prevents Chrome from requesting same images. With this approach, each image is requested only once.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var i = -1;
                setInterval(function() {
                    ++i;
                    if(i >= 4) {
                        i = 0;
                    }
                    $('.img').hide();
                    $('#img' + i).show();
                }, 100);
            });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- using multiple images with display: none, src is fixed in HTML (not changed by JS) -->
        <img id="img0" class="img" width="50" height="50" style="display: none;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIH1O.jpg?s=48&g=1">
        <img id="img1" class="img" width="50" height="50" style="display: none;" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/9aa2aa68144b2781ac025a29c83bbdd4?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG">
        <img id="img2" class="img" width="50" height="50" style="display: none;" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/c0377fc1b08293d3362611978913a32b?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG">
        <img id="img3" class="img" width="50" height="50" style="display: none;" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/07f36acea2b942f61102221f92f62f6e?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG">
    </body>
</html>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/agw6y08o/)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is the right behavior as "Memory Cache" stores and loads resources to and from Memory (RAM). So this is much faster but it is non-persistent. Content is available until you close the Browser.

"Disk Cache" is persistent. Cached resources are stored and loaded to and from disk.

For more info on how Chrome caches works (memory and disk), please refer to [this link](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest).

Comment: Informative. I've edited my question, see if you can answer my question (last line)

Comment: If you actually want to see the image again you have to do the request, then your browser will not perform a real request but will load it from cache.
As long as you manage images changing src, a request cycle management will occur. What you can do is retrieve instead images the firs time by xhr if not already fetched (once fetched add url in another array to prevent xhr to be done), encode it in base64, add it to an array and draw it to a canvas. When switching image, check if already in array, otherwise do a new xhr. What's the problem with cache ?